# Ansible и git, клонирование списка проектов

Tags: python, git, ansible

- Дистрибутив(ы): Debian stretch/jessie
- Ansible: 2.7.8
- Репозиторий: git/gitolite

При клонировании проектов часть вываливается с ошибкой:

```
The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_git_payload_LXVzTo/__main__.py", line 450, in clone
    os.makedirs(dest_dirname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)

failed: [ismdev-stretch64] (item=lib-log-perl master) => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin 'git://git.local-pgojects.org/lib-log-perl master.git' '/opt/local-projects/git/lib-log-perl m$
ster'",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "accept_hostkey": true,
            "archive": null,
            "bare": false,
            "clone": true,
            "depth": null,
            "dest": "/opt/local-projects/git/lib-log-perl master",
            "executable": null,
            "force": true,
            "key_file": null,
            "recursive": true,
            "reference": null,
            "refspec": null,
            "remote": "origin",
            "repo": "git://git.local-pgojects.org/lib-log-perl master.git",
            "separate_git_dir": null,
            "ssh_opts": null,
            "track_submodules": false,
            "umask": null,
            "update": true,
            "verify_commit": false,
            "version": "master"
        }
    },
    "item": "lib-log-perl master",
    "msg": "Cloning into '/opt/local-projects/git/lib-log-perl master'...\nfatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported:
/lib-log-perl master.git",
    "rc": 128,
    "stderr": "Cloning into '/opt/local-projects/git/lib-log-perl master'...\nfatal: remote error: access denied or repository not export$
d: /lib-log-perl master.git\n",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Cloning into '/opt/local-projects/git/lib-log-perl master'...",
        "fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /lib-log-perl master.git"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

Хотя при клонировании в ручную все "ок" (?)

```
root@stretch64:/opt/local-projects/git# git clone git://git.local-projects.org/lib-log-perl.git
Cloning into 'lib-log-perl'...
remote: Counting objects: 232, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (166/166), done.
remote: Total 232 (delta 83), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (232/232), 30.33 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (83/83), done.
```

Где искать ошибку в Ansible или настройках локального репозитория?

Comment: Вы, видимо, в адрес репозитория зачем-то запихали `master.git`, но это очевидно не является частью адреса и его нужно убрать

Comment: @andreymal Смех в том, что в списке 20 репозиториев с одинаковым форматом, и только некоторые вылетают с этой ошибкой, 80% клонируются.

Comment: А с более ранней `v2.7.7` тоже плохо?